# Load Nuxt project to exist express app

Tags: express, vue.js, middleware, nuxt.js

Could not find a trace over the network.

Is there a way to load Nuxt project as a middleware for other express server?

The documentation is just explaining how to run the nuxt-server.
(I'm familiar with the 'static' option, but I would like to keep the SSR behavior)

I've transferred my Vue (non-nuxt) application to Nuxt, so I already have a server infrastructure that the nuxt-production-server is interrupting,
so I would like to load a build or middleware to my existing express server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See official nuxt template -> https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template

Or you can use something like this

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')
const config = require('./nuxt.config.js')
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
const app = require('express')()
app.use((req, res) => setTimeout(() => {
  return nuxt.render(req, res)
}, 0))
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0')
```